# Can Paypal Pro cause problems to my old paypal website?

Tags: php, joomla, paypal

Five years ago a webmaster of mine created a php website **A** with IPN payments by paypal.
That webmaster is not with me anymore.
Now I am creating a Joomla website **B** with a new webmaster and I want to use Paypal Pro.
If I request to Paypal to use Paypal Pro, then website A will continue working as usual? Or Paypal Pro will cause some problems to the site **A**?

I mean Paypal Pro is separate from Standard Paypal and can work in parallel?

Comment: You should probably contact PayPal themselves

Answer (score 0):

Adding PayPal Pro will not effect your current integration(s).